# Backing up very large MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, database

What is the best way to backup very large MySQL database (Gigas of info)?

Comment: Put it in the correct gear and slowly push your foot down on the pedal until it is in the correct position.  If it is very large, have friends helping you to signal incase you bump into anything you can't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqldump is generally the best and fastest way to backup a database, since it is a tool thats delivered with mysql rightaway.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database engine if you are using MYISAM or ARCHIVE tables you can use mysqlhotcopy which allows for backing up the tables without having to shut down MySQL

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html